# Add my external application (.run) within custom rhel image using osbuild

Tags: rhel, cockpit

Using cockpit image builder (os-build backend) to create custom rocky 9 iso image.
For my use case, I want to add my own application (.run file) to this custom iso image.
I tried using os-build's external repository feature without success.

Can someone guide me on this? Is it even possible to add external .run file to iso image using os-build?